# How to generate an autonumber using jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp, autonumber

I want code in jsp or javascript which will generate numbers serially and automatically when ever registered by the user.

Comment: 1) You really don't want to do this in JavaScript. 2) What DB are you using? This is to be solved in the DB side, not in the Java/JSP side.

Answer (score 1):

If you are saving user in db then set your ID column `autoIncreament` no need to code for that.

Comment: PreparedStatement stat=conn.prepareStatement("insert into Registration(regno,fname)values(?,?);                stat.setString(1,?);
stat.setString(2,fname);                            stat.executeUpdate();             If regno is a field which i want to increment then what should i write down in setString field.I am getting server error if i skip this first field name in the setString field

Comment: @Samiksha: try `"insert into Registration(fname) values(?)"`

Comment: I tried this insert into Registration(fname) values(?) and stat.setString(1,fname); then it runs but data didn't save in DB. Also tried for stat.setString(2,fname); but it gives error in this line.

Comment: @Samiksha: which database are you using? mysql? oracle? ms access? Because it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Samiksha, I think you are looking for [UUID](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) .A UUID represents a 128-bit value.

Read this post to [generate Unique Ids](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56).

Directly use it as:

```
UUID uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID();
```

Good Luck